# ASP.net MVC 5: updating a jquery variable from a session variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a bit at my limits of my knowledge and research, so I'm reaching out to see if someone out there can assist.

Situation: I have a web page where a person presses a button to browse for an excel file and then presses another button to import that file. The controller then passes the file to a background worker and creates users from it. While the process happens in the background div in the view is refreshed every 2 seconds to show the progress of completed users. All that is working, but when the background worker is done processing the file I need the refresh to stop. My problem is that jquery is only fetching the session variable once and then essentially hard coding the initial result in.

here is the code that is running, debuggers were put in so I could see if the variable changed. Specifically looking at variable named "done":

```
<script>
    $('#upload').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                const refresh = setInterval(function () {
                    var done = '@Session["BulkCreateDone"].ToString()';
                    if ( done == "True") {
                            debugger; <===== never gets hit due to "done" never updating to "True"
                            clearInterval(refresh);
                    };
                    debugger; <======= gets hit every loop
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/BulkCreation/List',
                        type: "Get",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#List').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                }, 2000);
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/BulkCreation/List',
                    type: "Get",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#List').html(result);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, status) {
                console.log(error, status);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example, there are 5 users in the file and it takes about 10 loops for the process to complete:

What I was expecting - 
Loop 1-10:
done = "False"

loop 11:
done = "True"

What actually happened - 
loop 1 through infinity:
done = "False"

Does anyone know how I can have jquery update the variable?

Update 1:
So I made a new method in my controller and had that pass a error back while the background process had not set the "done" flag to true and altered my jquery and ajax code. I put the working code below for those interested.

```
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if ('@Session["BulkCreateDone"].ToString()' == 'True') {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/BulkCreation/List',
                type: "Get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#List').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#upload').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                const refresh = setInterval(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/BulkCreation/List',
                        type: "Get",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#List').html(result);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/BulkCreation/BulkDone',
                                type: "Get",
                                success: function (result) {
                                    clearInterval(refresh);
                                    $('#btn').css('display', 'inline');
                                    $('#importing').css('display', 'none');
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '/BulkCreation/Index',
                                        type: "Get",
                                        success: function (result) {
                                            window.location.href = response.Url;
                                        }
                                    });
                                },
                                error: function (e) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }, 2000);
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, status) {
                console.log(error, status);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#btn').on('click', function () {
        $('#btn').css('display', 'none');
        $('#importing').css('display', 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is natural behavior. Once code is generated you can't expect view to automatically update values. This should be done in controller. Create ajax function that will get current value from controller and pass it to function. Bottom line you need another ajax call.

Comment: I'm not expecting it to update the values automatically, but it seems to be replacing the code, meaning the "var done = '@Session["BulkCreateDone"].ToString()';" part of the code turns into "var done = 'False';" on the first and all loops moving forward. The controller method that gets called in the loop updates that session variable and I have tracked it so I know it is updating.